# Can I use peat as a substrate for oyster mushroom growing?

Tags: mushrooms

I want to grow mushrooms at home. For small scale. I have done some research found that oysters are the easiest to start so I bought some grain spawn. For the substrate I am out of US and I dont knoe how to find wood chips and stuff and I didnt want to buy hay as it is messy indoors. I want to use peat moss as my substrate. Is it possible o do I need to buy woodchips and etc.

Q: Can I use peat moss as a substrate for growing oysters?

Comment: I have only seen certain trees listed as site for oyster mushrooms ; that is the only places I have found them ( and Sweetgum trees which are not mentioned in the listings).

Answer (score 1):

I would expect peat moss to be too acidic. Even with wood chips, oyster mushrooms benefit from hydrated lime or some other pH raising calcium.

But you are in luck because oyster mushrooms will grow in almost anything. Surely you could find some of these locally:

- Newspaper
- Cardboard
- Coffee grounds
- Hardwood animal bedding
- straw (NOT hay)
- any kind off agricultural grain waste - husks, etc.

Please post an update on what you eventually use. Try a few things.

Answer (score 0):

I inoculated black morel onto hickory smoking chips that I boiled over the stove. It started to grow within two days. Today I boiled some peat moss and strained it. I had just added it to the mix now that it was cool enough. I'm hoping It will help the mycelium span through the woodchips better being they was chunky wood chips.